# Weird effect of AVR C on USB-serial communication

Tags: serial, atmega328

I recently decided to learn direct port manipulation instead of builtin arduino routines.

First I tried this piece of code

```
void setup() {
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
Serial.println("on");
delay(500);                  
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   
Serial.println("off");
delay(500);                       
}
```

This program on running instantly established connection with the serial monitor on my arduino IDE.

But when I try this code

```
int main(void)
{
Serial.begin(9600);
DDRB = B11111111;
while(1)
{
PORTB = PORTB | 0x20;
Serial.println("off");
_delay_ms(500);
PORTB = PORTB & 0xDF;
Serial.println("on");
_delay_ms(500);
}
}
```

But this program is taking some time, about 5-10 seconds to establish serial connection. Also delay() is not working too. When I use delay() instead of _delay_ms(), the entire arduino board freezes like a computer and stops blinking the LED instead LED is fully ON.

I tried is on several programs, while "setup-loop" program connects instantly, AVR C programs does not.

why does it happen?

Comment: Because normally `main()` initializes all the appropriate hardware and timers. You're circumventing that with your own `main()` so nothing Ardunioy works.

Comment: I should be most grateful if you could elaborate that in an answer.

Comment: please indent your code correctly .... beginners that might be browsing the quetions should be exposed to correctly formatted code no matter how simple the code listing is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining your own `main()` you are circumventing the Arduino startup procedures.

Normally with Arduino code `main()` first runs an `init()` function before `setup()` and (repeatedly) `loop()`.  This `init()` function will configure, amongst other things, the timer for `millis()` and `delay()`.

This is the normal `main()` for a basic AVR-based board:

```
int main(void)
{
    init();

    initVariant();

#if defined(USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif
    
    setup();
    
    for (;;) {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }   
     
    return 0;
}
```

It first initializes common functions, then board-specific ones (normally nothing), and if applicable, the USB interface (for ATMega32U4 based boards, like the Leonardo).

Only then does it go on to run your sketch.

If you want to use both your own `main()` and Arduino functions like `delay()` then you will have to call those initialization routines before running the rest of your code.

Comment: Could you explain the significance of "serialEventRun"?

Comment: If you haven't defined a `serialEvent()` function then it has no significance at all. If you have defined one then it runs it.

Comment: What is the purpose of initVariant()?

Comment: That is the bit where I say `then board-specific ones (normally nothing)`

Comment: I just rewrote my code to include just init() and nothing else, the serial communication, both read and write, is now working. So my question, is     USBDevice.attach()
 necessary?

Comment: Only if you're on an ATMega32U4 or similar chip where the USB is a real USB connection, not a UART connection through a USB bridge chip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111596/discussion-between-aswin-venu-and-majenko).